# Why is an BatchIndices object not an iterator?

Tags: python-2.7, iterator

Here is the code:

```
class BatchIndices(object):

    def __init__(self, n, bs, shuffle=False):
        self.n,self.bs,self.shuffle = n,bs,shuffle
        print(n,bs)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.idxs = (np.random.permutation(self.n) 
                 if self.shuffle else np.arange(0, self.n))
        self.curr = 0

    def __next__(self):
        with self.lock:
        if self.curr >= self.n: self.reset()
            ni = min(self.bs, self.n-self.curr)
            res = self.idxs[self.curr:self.curr+ni]
            self.curr += ni
            print(res)
            return res
bi = BatchIndices(5,3, True)
[next(bi) for o in range(5)]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-7f3487846737> in <module>()
  1 bi = BatchIndices(5,3, True)
----> 2 [next(bi) for o in range(5)]

TypeError: BatchIndices object is not an iterator
```

I have no idea why the 'BatchIndices' object is not an iterator even next() object in class BatchIndices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Python 2. You need `next()` because `__next__` was introduced in Python 3:

```
import threading

import numpy as np

class BatchIndices(object):

    def __init__(self, n, bs, shuffle=False):
        self.n,self.bs,self.shuffle = n,bs,shuffle
        print(n,bs)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.idxs = (np.random.permutation(self.n)
                 if self.shuffle else np.arange(0, self.n))
        self.curr = 0

    def __next__(self):
        with self.lock:
            if self.curr >= self.n:
                self.reset()
                ni = min(self.bs, self.n-self.curr)
                res = self.idxs[self.curr:self.curr+ni]
                self.curr += ni
                print(res)
                return res

    next = __next__


bi = BatchIndices(5,3, True)

[next(bi) for o in range(5)]
```

Output:

```
(5, 3)
```